# Why would a stack trace skip a function that obviously has to have been called for the following functions to have been reached?

Tags: c++, debugging, callstack

Given a setup like this, where DoFooStuff() is called:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void DoFooStuff(); // calls Bar::DoBarStuff()
}

class Bar {
public:
    void DoBarStuff(); // Calls Bar::DoInternalBarStuff()
protected:
    void DoInternalBarStuff();
}
```

What could make it possible that my stack trace could show exactly this?:

```
Type                   Function
void                   Bar::DoInternalBarStuff()
void                   Foo::DoFooStuff()
```

The only reference to DoInternalBarStuff() is in DoBarStuff(). DoInternalBarStuff() asserts on it's first line:

```
assert(false);
```

And that is the location where the stack trace is taken from.

Comment: None of these functions are declared as inline in the headers. Thanks for the suggestion though. Also I like your name :D

Comment: The compiler is free to inline any function, even if not declared inline. Any compiler worth its salt will inline functions as a matter of course.

Comment: @zindorsky: would that sort of behavior be limited to release/shipping builds?

Comment: Nevermind, I found an answer to that question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626248/does-gcc-inline-c-functions-without-the-inline-keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the call to Bar::DoBarInternalStuff the last statement in Bar::DoBarStuff?  If so, the compiler most likely replaced Bar::DoBarStuff's stack frame with Bar::DoBarInternalStuff's when Bar::DoBarInternalStuff was called.

This kind of [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization is fairly common in C/C++ compilers.  It reduces the stack depth required when a recursive function can be arranged such that the recursive call is the last call in the function.

Comment: Okay, yes, this is what happened. Thanks so much for helping me make sense of this! <3

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the compiler does automatic inlining at certain optimization levels. Learn new things every day. :)

[Does GCC inline C++ functions without the 'inline' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626248/does-gcc-inline-c-functions-without-the-inline-keyword)

(Thanks for the helpful comments that showed me this.)